# Select an item in an html dropdown list only with an option Id in javascript/JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

I have to select an option element in a dropdown list.
My html form is generated from a xsl template and could have several dropdown list/select part.
I only know the option Id to select but not the select parent tag.

Is there a way to select an item in a dropdown list only with an option id without knowing its select parent tag ?

Thank you

Comment: post html, post js. create jsfiddle,what did you try till now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can either do:

```
$('#optionID'.prop('selected', true);
```

Or:

```
$('#optionID').closest('select').val($('#optionID').val());
```